# What is the risk of opening network port?

Tags: networking, security, port

What can someone do if i write a program to open a TCP port and run, lets say an echo server? Can some one access data on my system? or any other risk of opening port?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable basic question, and I was a bit appalled to see it down voted and at -1 when there 9 up votes on the answer. If you find the answer useful, maybe don't kick the asker in the shins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how well the program is written and under what credentials your server program runs as. For instance say you allocate a fixed-length buffer to read from the socket, and then you read in more than the allocated size, it might be possible to craft a server requests that overruns the buffer on the stack and overwrites the return address. At that point the hacker could re-point the return address to be on the (overrun) buffer, which could contain actual code. Then, if your server program runs as root/administrator you're letting the code being executed in that context.

Comment: Note, while **this is actually possible** it's also getting more unlikely as OSes/Apps use the NX bit, and measures are taken to avoid buffer overflow problems. Also, most Linux distros have known priv elevation exploits, so even a user process might lead to rooting.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is vulnerable, a hacker could possibly execute code on your system with privileges of your program. Or perhaps he could arrange a DoS attack (your program would consume all CPU or memory or disk space and everything would stop working and collapse :-) ).

In the past one also could find a bug in the OS TCP/IP stack and exploit it. So even if your program was perfect, there was a chance of getting into troubles with an open port. However I haven't heard of such bugs for a while now.